# Bumble bees and wasps

Tags: zoology, communication

Location:India

My father was telling me yesterday that wasps were building a nest over an abandoned store room in our backyard...But he noticed that the wasps were attacked by a bunch of bumblebees...And the two were locked up in a duel.Several wasps were also found dead on the land...

Today he told me that the nest had almost diminished and several bumblebees were surrounding it...which seemed like they were destroying it

*My question is:*

Why would bumblebees destroy the wasp nest?

I guessed that they would build their own nest instead (after a few days perhaps) but there were plenty of other places in the yard too like there is big mango tree... it's only a guess and I am too curious to know any biological cause.